# How to restrict a user to not to open any external website while being logged in my web application?

Tags: javascript, php, browser

I am working on an assessment site. On the test window the user is required to be focused and not to skip/open any other website. I checked with JavaScript but not have enough to do so.

Comment: And what about another browser ? What about incognito Window?????? Instead decrease the time limit of the answer instead

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do that? The user will have a plenty of other ways to access google. I think it is a lot of effort in a useless (and annoying) feature.

Comment: already done a time limit restrictions..cheaters can cheat any way but can we restrict him by doing so easy thing in the same browser?

Comment: You could employ [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) on newer browsers to at least detect if user has moved out of your page.

Comment: @bemontibeller yes he will have many ways that's why I have given above comment & already thought about the usability but atleast it should not be easy to cheat by glass of water

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent user from opening a new tab/window or a separate browser instance.

You can hovewer detect if user has left your page and moved to another window or tab - you would need to use [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

If user moves out of your page, alert them, or play a sound etc, or do something else to warn them that they're not supposed to do that while doing an exam. Or just punish them by a point ;)

Simple sample (from MDN basically, with minor adjustment):

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
      console.log("Hidden");
  } else  {
      console.log("Visible");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamituel/7sckxy4h/)

Note that page visiblity API [is not supported in some older browsers, most notably IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#Browser_compatibility).

If you want to be really intrusive, you could use [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) when user moves away from your tab. In many browsers (I tested it in latest Chrome and Fx Nightly) that will switch tab back to yours, effectively preventing user from switching a tab within same window. That would not help with switching to some other window though - for instance, on Mac I can move to another workspace even with this alert in place.

[Example Fiddle with alert](http://jsfiddle.net/kamituel/7sckxy4h/1/)

Comment: yes..but can we restrict the checkbox 'Prevent it from creating..'??

Comment: As I said in the answer - no, you cannot do that. And you'll never will be, because the OS or window manager is in control of all the windows. If you need that kind of a solution, you need some additional constraints implemented there. But in such a case this is no longer a Javascript question, not even programming one, it's a question of finding a right OS-level tool for that.